# mysql foreign key contraints

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not very familiar with mysql and when I try and update the database, it gives me the following error:

> *Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lhollowa`.`Concert`, CONSTRAINT `Concert_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BandID`) REFERENCES `Bands` (`BandID`))*

I am pretty clueless as to what I am doing wrong, could someone point me in the right direction?

Here is some of what I have (the rest would take up too much room).

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Bands`;
 /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
 /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
 CREATE TABLE `Bands` (
   `BandID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `BandName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`BandID`)
 );

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Songs`;

 CREATE TABLE `Songs` (
   `SongID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `SongTitle` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`SongID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=481 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


 CREATE TABLE `Concert` (
 `ConcertID` int (40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `BandID` INT (40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Concert_Time` varchar (20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Venue_Name` varchar (40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Number_Seats` int (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Number_Tickets` int (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (ConcertID),
 FOREIGN KEY (BandID) REFERENCES Bands(BandID)
 );

 INSERT INTO `Concert` VALUES (82838283,1111111, 'noon', 'the razz', 139, 138);
```

Comment: Does Bands have a row where BandID = 1111111?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are attempting to insert a record into the `Concert` table before the `BandId` exists in the `Bands` table.

A foreign key is a constraint between two tables.  The foreign key identifies a column(s) in one table that refers to a column(s) in another table.

Since you have a foreign key set up between the `Concert` and `Bands` table, the record must exist in `Bands` or you will get the error message. So you have to insert the band with id `1111111` into `Bands` before you can create a concert record for them.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d71e/1) showing a working version.

Comment: wow, I feel really dumb that it was something so simple. Thank you very much though!

Comment: @LucasLusnikovHolloway no need to feel dumb, we have all done it...or at least I have done it before. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert or update the `concert` table with a `bandid` that is not found in the `bands` table, or deleting a band that has existing concerts associated with it.

This typically because you are doing the operations in the wrong order; you must make sure that at every point the data us consistent.

There is another alternative to "doing updates in the right order": You can temporarily turn off such constraints, make your changes in any order, then turn the constraints back on again:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
-- update, insert whatever
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

This doesn't mean you avoid keeping the data consistent, but it does mean you don't have to worry about the order in which you make changes to the dara.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the band into the Bands table before you insert into the Concert table.